# Deep pick using lodash/underscore

Tags: javascript, performance, underscore.js, lodash.js

#### Use Case

`_.pick` creates a shallow clone of an object given a predicate that identifies which keys to keep. `pickDeep` would perform a deep clone of the object and would "pick" up all nested objects containing the given keys. All containers containing the nested objects would remain and would not be removed.

#### Requirements

- Recursively apply a `pick` to each level in an object.
- If a property is an `object`/`array`, then apply a `pick`.
- Keep all `object`/`array` only if the descendant properties fulfill the `pick`.

#### Improvements

I'd like any constructive criticism to improve this code, but I'm mainly interested in advice pertaining to:

- Readability
- Flexibility
- Performance
- Implementing this with `_.pick` and `_.cloneDeep`

#### Function

([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/39nqb/2/))

```
function pickDeep(collection, identity, thisArg) {
    var picked = _.pick(collection, identity, thisArg);
    var collections = _.pick(collection, _.isObject, thisArg);

    _.each(collections, function(item, key, collection) {
        var object;
        if (_.isArray(item)) {
            object = _.reduce(item, function(result, value) {
                var picked = pickDeep(value, identity, thisArg);
                if (!_.isEmpty(picked)) {
                    result.push(picked);
                }
                return result;
            }, []);
        } else {
            object = pickDeep(item, identity, thisArg);
        }

        if (!_.isEmpty(object)) {
            picked[key] = object;
        }

    });

    return picked;
}
```

#### Test Data

```
var data = {
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
    c: 7,
    d: {
        a: 65,
        z: 6,
        d: {
            a: 65,
            k: 5
        }
    },
    e: [
        {a : 5},
        {b : 6},
        {c : 7}
    ],
    f: [
        { 
            b : [  { a: 5, z: 5 } ],
            c : 6
        },
        {
            g: 0   
        }
    ]
};
```

#### Test Cases

```
var testCase1 = { a: 5, b: 6};
pickDeep(testCase1, 'a'); // {a : 5}
var testCase2 = { a: 5, b: { a: 1}, c: { b: 3}};
pickDeep(testCase2, 'a'); // {a: 5, b: {a: 1}}
var testCase3 = { a: 5, b: [ { a: 1}, { c: 2}, {d: 3} ], c: [ {c: 2}, {d : 3}]}
pickDeep(testCase3, 'a'); //{ a: 5, b: [ {a: 1} ]}
var testCase4 = [ {a: 5}, {b: 2}, {c: {a :3 }}, {d: [ {a: 4}] }, z: [ { f: 34}] ];
pickDeep(testCase4, 'a'); // [ {a:5}, {c: {a:3}}, {d: [ {a:4}]}];
```

#### Execution Code

```
function isIn(collection) {
    return function(value, key) {
        return _.contains(collection, key);
    }
}

console.log(pickDeep(data, isIn(['a', 'c'])));
```

Comment: And what is your question? I haven't tested, but I think it does, what it should. On first sight, I find nothing to complain about. So I am fine with it :]

Comment: @ThomasJunk I think I've found what was wrong with this code. I'll have to update this post, but what was bothering me was that a lot of the code re-implements the logic that's already available in lodash/underscore. I think the better solution is to wrap the `_.pick` in logic that allows for a deep traverse, rather than re-implementing the pick functionality.

Comment: Can you provide some more examples, I read your code I'm not sure how you want to handle some cases

Comment: @megawac I've updated the page with the requirements and test cases. I have this nagging feeling that this can easily be done with `_.cloneDeep` and `_.pick` together, but I haven't been able to connect the dots.

Comment: `pick` always returns an object. But your test cases want it to return an array? Your code fails testCase4 due to that consideration

Comment: @megawac Ahhh.. good catch.. hmm.. this adds more logic as I now need to convert the object back into an array... Going to give it a shot leveraging `_.cloneDeep`. It might be the better way to go than re-implementing the wheel of stepping through the object.

Comment: How do you want it handled I have a solution ready, always an object? or array if array otherwise object

Comment: Also do you want it restricted to own properties or in properties

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's the most elegant way I can think of writing this. I use `transform` to handle both Arrays and Objects as your tests showed you wanted to support them, though as pointed out in comments your code didn't.

These changes also allow you to use more than 2 pick properties (`pickDeep(set, 'a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e'])`) as you can with the normal `pick`/`omit`.

For `lodash` 3 and `underscore` 1.8? you'll need to change `_.createCallback` to `_.iteratee` the rest of the code should remain the same.

```
function pickDeep(collection, predicate, thisArg) {
    if (_.isFunction(predicate)) {
        predicate = _.createCallback(predicate, thisArg);
    } else {
        var keys = _.flatten(_.rest(arguments));
        predicate = function(val, key) {
            return _.contains(keys, key);
        }
    }

    return _.transform(collection, function(memo, val, key) {
        var include = predicate(val, key);
        if (!include && _.isObject(val)) {
            val = pickDeep(val, predicate);
            include = !_.isEmpty(val);
        }
        if (include) {
            _.isArray(collection) ? memo.push(val) : memo[key] = val;
        }
    });
}
```

This also fixes a the need to check `pickDeep({a: [{a: 1}]})` twice to add it to the picked object

Comment: Very nice solution. Just a quick question, what is the difference between `transform` and `reduce`? Is the difference that `transform` will exit early if `false` is returned?

Comment: Heh I've answered that one before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536627/whats-the-difference-between-transform-and-reduce-in-lodash/21536978#21536978

Comment: `_.createCallback` was deprecated to `_.callback`. On large collections I get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: 2 things: Latest lodash v4.6.1, `_.rest` requires a func so this errors out there. 2nd, is it possible to use this to "omit" certain props based on a criteria?

Comment: The `_.rest` this refers to is now `_.tail`.  I'm not sure what you mean by the "criteria" statement. it uses `_.iteratee` to create the predicate, so it should behave like any other lodash mehtod

Comment: Criteria is any function that return truthy/falsy. Your solution actually doesn't work the same way as OP's `pickDeep`. E.g., I want to omit a property if it passes certain condition. With your solution, all I get is property name, so I cannot check for things like `return prop.xyz == something` in the predicate. I'm not criticizing but trying to understand how it all works.

Comment: You're correct, it should of been `predicate(val, key)`. Feel free to correct if you desire

Comment: To make this work with Lodash v4.17.1:
* `_.createCallback -> _.iteratee`
* `_.rest -> _.tail`
* `_.contains -> _.includes`

Answer (score 5):

I haven't worked with underscore yet (gasp), BUT, I'd like to give what I can here in case you get no better answer soon!

### Readability

Your formatting is nearly flawless. However, [Douglas Crockford says](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html):

> If a function literal is anonymous, there should be one space between
>   the word function and the ( (left parenthesis). If the space is
>   omited, then it can appear that the function's name is function, which
>   is an incorrect reading.

So if you're alright with some nit-picky feedback, try:

```
function (item, key, collection)
```

rather than

```
function(item, key, collection)
```

### Flexibility

Try breaking down your main function into simpler, sub functions, that each have very specific jobs. This keeps your code decoupled, and extensible. I call this *Single Function Function*. [I learned it here.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180585/are-there-any-oo-principles-that-are-practically-applicable-for-javascript) (Read that, and you instantly evolve as a JavaScript Programmer.)

Comment: I think you're spot on the breaking down the main function. I realized that the fundamental problem I'm trying to solve is to apply a function against a piece of deeply nested data. I think the solution is rather than create a `pickDeep` function, I should be creating a `nest` function. Then it would be more generalized and could be used with other methods within `underscore` or any other library for that matter.